# JavaScript Functional Classes

Tags: javascript, oop

I am learning object oriented programming in JavaScript from an Udacity course. I would like to know which among the below is the best technique to create an Functional Object and why.

First code:

```
var Car = function(loc){
    var Obj = {loc:loc};
    extend(Obj, Car.methods);
    return Obj;
}

Car.methods = {
    move: function(){
        this.loc++;
    }
};
```

Second code:

Isnt the Above code same as:

```
var Car = function(loc){
    var Obj = {loc:loc};
    Obj.move= function(){
        this.loc++;
    }
    return Obj;
}
```

Third code

```
var Car = function(loc){
    var Obj = {loc:loc};
    Obj.move=move;
    return Obj;
}

move=function(){
    this.loc++;
};
```

I just want to know, which style of coding one should follow. I understand that the third code is better than second because more instances of functions are created whenever we use the Car function. Doesn't the first code create more instance of the same function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: None of those, learn to use prototypes.

Comment: in third case, if you call `Car(...)` before `move=function` you get exception

Comment: or use ECMA6 standards for `Object` to create objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer: None of the above. Try something like this:

```
function Car(loc) {
    this.loc = loc;
}

Car.prototype.move = function () {
    this.loc++;
};

var obj = new Car(someLoc);

obj.move();
```

This uses object prototyping which is JavaScript's implementation of object-oriented programming. You can read more about prototypes and inheritance [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

The reason why this is the preferred method is because it organizes your code a lot better, and the object itself can actually be identified as a `Car` using [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof). I'll extend the example below to demonstrate some properties of inheritance:

```js
// Vehicle constructor
function Vehicle(wheels, speed, loc) {
    this.wheels = wheels;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.loc = loc;
}

// instance method move
Vehicle.prototype.move = function () {
    this.loc += this.speed;
};

// Car constructor
function Car(loc) {
    // JS equivalent of super()
    Vehicle.call(this, 4, 60, loc);
}

// override instance method move
Car.prototype.move = function () {
    this.loc++;
};

// make Car inherit from Vehicle
Car.prototype.__proto__ = Vehicle.prototype;

// construct instance of Car with loc of 0
var obj = new Car(0);

// obj is instance of Vehicle...
if (obj instanceof Vehicle) {
    console.log('wheels: %d', obj.wheels); // 4
    console.log('speed: %d', obj.speed); // 60
    console.log('loc: %d', obj.loc); // 0
}

// ...and also instance of Car
if (obj instanceof Car) {
    obj.move();
    console.log('loc: %d', obj.loc); // 1, not 60
}
```

This demonstrates how you can use the prototype chain to override instance methods, and also how inheritance allows `obj` to be an instance of both `Car` and `Vehicle`. I hope you can see now why using the prototype chain is the preferred method.

Comment: But Out of curiosity which among those three is a better technique.

Comment: @Karma I'd have to go with the last one then because it's the only one that would actually work. `extend` is not a valid function in the first example, and in the second example `move` is not actually a function of `obj`.

Comment: @Karma well I see you've updated your answer. I'd still go with the last one because in the second example you're making a copy of the `move` function for every instance you make rather than using the same function for all instances as you do in the last example.

Comment: Thanks. What the extend function ought to do is copy the contents of the object. So i am assuming the second and first be the same.